# "No matching distribution found for mediapipe." on macOS High Sierra python3.11.4 pip 23.2.1

Tags: python-3.x, macos, macos-high-sierra, mediapipe

```
python -m pip install mediapipe

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mediapipe (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mediapipe
```

First of all, I removed all old pythons (2.7, 3.6). Then installed python3.11.4 and pip 23.2.1.

Now, I try to install Mediapipe

```
python -m pip install mediapipe
```

And got errors:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mediapipe (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mediapipe
```

Whats wrong? How can I resolve this trouble?

Comment: I'm not familiar with mediapipe, but from their pypi distributions files page (https://pypi.org/project/mediapipe/#files), there's no compatible distribution for python 3.11 - macos 10.13.x (high sierra). From their docs, minimum for macos seems to be 10.15.x: https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/framework/getting_started/troubleshooting#python_pip_install_failure

Comment: Gino Mempin!
Yes! You are right! I missed this moment

Answer (score 0):

It seems mediapipe (as of `0.10.3`) is not supported for your Python 3.11 + macOS High Sierra 10.13.x combination.

This can be seen from the available wheels on mediapipe's PyPi page (https://pypi.org/project/mediapipe/#files) that, as of mediapipe `0.10.3`, the only wheels for python 3.11 are for macOS 11.x and up (actually, *all* the `macosx` wheels are for `11_0` and up). Your macOS version is simply not supported any more.

The error is also documented in the mediapipe docs:  https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/framework/getting_started/troubleshooting#python_pip_install_failure:

> #### Python pip install failure
>
> The error message:
>
> ```
> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mediapipe
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for mediapipe
> ```
>
> after running `pip install mediapipe` usually indicates that there is no qualified MediaPipe Python for your system. Please note that MediaPipe Python PyPI officially supports the **64-bit** version of Python 3.7 to 3.10 on the following OS:
>
> - x86_64 Linux
> - x86_64 macOS 10.15+
> - amd64 Windows
>
> If the OS is currently supported and you still see this error, please make sure that both the Python and pip binary are for Python 3.7 to 3.10. Otherwise, please consider building the MediaPipe Python package locally by following the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/framework/getting_started/python#building-mediapipe-python-package).

**You will have to switch to a compatible Python - OS version.**

There is a "[here](https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/framework/getting_started/python#building-mediapipe-python-package)" in their docs for building the package yourself, but unfortunately that leads to a 404 page. You can try checking out the steps for installing mediapipe *from source* in the **Installing on macOS** section: https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/framework/getting_started/install#installing_on_macos.

There is also this suggestion in the [Setup guide for Python](https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/solutions/setup_python) section:

> Note: If you are testing or experimenting with MediaPipe tasks, consider using [Colaboratory](https://colab.research.google.com/), a Python notebook environment that requires no setup and runs entirely in the cloud.